# Wrong redirecting but only standard WP-Rules in .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

### **Problem:**

I have a download link with an ip as "site name"

http://192.168.1.1/downloads/file.txt

This is redirecting to

https://www.mywebsite.comdownloads/file.txt

Now I want it of course to redirect correctly to

https://www.mywebsite.com/downloads/file.txt

### **What I've checked:**

I've checked some WP options. There was nothing obvious.. I've checked the .htacess. There were only the standard WP rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas? Is there maybe another file where I can set rules?

Comment: Rewrite rules can be set in the Apache config file as well. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this rewrite in .htaccess file (before #BEGIN WordPress rules)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^192\.168\.1\.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/downloads\/file.txt$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/downloads/file.txt [L,R=301]
```